# Most dynamic dynamic programming language

Tags: programming-languages

It seems I've got to agree with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/407415#407415) when it states that

> [...] code in dynamically typed languages follows static-typing conventions

Much dynamic language code I encounter does indeed seem to be quite *static* (thinking of PHP) whereas dynamic approaches look somewhat clumsy or unnecessary instead.

Most of the time, it's just about omitting type signatures, which, in the context of type-inference/structural typing, doesn't even have to imply dynamic typing at all.

So my question (and it's not meant to be too subjective) is, in which *dynamic languages* or *fields of application* are all these more advanced dynamic language features (that couln't be replicated in static/compiled languages *that easily*) *actually and idomatically used*.

Examples:

- Reflection
- First-class continuations
- Runtime object alteration/generation
- Metaprogramming
- Run-time code evaluation
- Non-existent member behaviour

What are useful applications for such techniques?

Comment: I don't want to be a pedant, but I think we need to define a "dynamic language" a little bit better, at least beyond these features. For example, Haskell is generally considered the paragon of a static language, but it has reflection, continuations, metaprogramming (see Template Haskell) and runtime code evaluation. Are we talking about dynamic versus static typing? Dynamic dispatch? What is "dynamic"?

Comment: @Chuck: Well, you're right and, to be honest, it isn't that easy. I'd just stick to the features I proposed, include all scripting languages/dynamically typed languages and do the rest ex negativo (No one will consider C++ to be a dynamic language) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All features you enumerate are also available in statically typed languages some with constraints.

- Reflection: Present in Java, C# (not type safe).
- First-class continuations: restricted support in Scala (maybe others)
- Runtime object alteration: Changing the type of an object is supported in a restriced form in C# with extension methods (will be in Java 7) and implicit type conversions in Scala. Although open class is not supported most of the use cases are covered by type conversions.
- Metaprogramming: I would say Metaprogramming is the heading for a lot of related features like reflection, type changes at runtime, AOP etc.

So there is not a lot left that is supported only by dynamic languages to discuss. Support for example for Reflection circumvents the type system but it is useful in certain situations where this kind of flexibility is needed. The same is true in dynamic languages.

The open class feature supported by Ruby is something that compiled languages will never support. It is the most flexible form of Metaprogramming possible (with all the implications: security, performance, maintainability.) You can change classes of the platform. It's used by Ruby on Rails to create methods of domain objects from metadata on the fly. In a statically typed language you have at least to create (or generate the code of) the interface of your domain object.

If you're looking for the "most dymanic languages" all [homoiconic languages](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HomoiconicLanguages) like LISP and Prolog are good candidates. Interestingly, C# is somewhat homoiconic with the expression trees in LINQ.

Comment: Neither extension methods nor implicits do alter or even extend a type **at runtime** - It's therefore 100% static. Moreover this question isn't about what features are *exclusively dynamic* but where they're used. I don't think one would idiomatically use runtime object generation in .NET.

Comment: @Dario Yes. Both are fully statically typed. My answer is more about the problem you try to solve with different language features. Statically typed languages find different solutions than dynamic languages to the same problems (like functional languages find different solution than imperative languages).

Comment: @Dario The question should be: What are the overall costs?

Comment: Of course and I want to know what unique solutions dynamic languages actually use.

Answer (score 8):

Some examples of widespread application of the above techniques are:

- Continuations make their appearance in web frameworks like Rails or Seaside.  They can be used to allow an API to fake a local context.  In Seaside or Rails this makes the API behave much more like a local GUI form handler than an HTTP request handler, which serves to simplify the task of coding the application's user interface elements.  However, although many dynamic languages have strong support for continuations they are certainly not unique to this type of language.
- Reflection is quite widely used for O/R mappers and serialisation, but many statically typed langages support reflection as well.  On duck typed languages it can be used to find out at runtime if a facility is implemented by looking at the object's metadata.  Some O/R mappers (and similar tools) work by implementing accesses to instance variables and redirecting the updates to a cached record in the data access layer.  This helps to make the persistence relatively transparent to the developer as the field accesses look much like local variables.
- Runtime object alteration is slightly useful (think monkey-patching) but mostly a gimmick.  There aren't many really killer uses for it that come to mind immediately, but people certainly do use it.  One possible use for it is fixing slightly broken behaviour when subclassing is not an option for some reason.
- Metaprogramming is quite a fuzzy definition for a term, but arguably generics and C++ templates are an example of metaprogramming - taking place on statically typed languages.  On languages with metaclass support, custom metaclasses can be used to implement particular behaviours such as singletons or object registries.
  Another metaprogramming example  is Smalltalk's `#notImplemented:` method which is called on attempts to invoke nonexistent methods.  The method name and parameters are supplied to the implementor of `#notImplemented:`, and can subsequently be used to construct a method invocation reflectively.  Trapping this can be used (for example) to implement generic proxy mechanisms.

LISP programmers would argue that LISP is the most dynamic language of all due to its first class support for diddling directly with the parse trees of the code (known as 'macros').  This facility makes implementing DSLs trivial in LISP - and integrating them transparently into your code base.

Answer (score 2):

You should visit [Douglas Crockford's Wrrrld Wide Web](http://www.crockford.com) and see his wizardry over Javascript. Javascript is usually written in pretty straightforward and simple manner, like slightly simplified C. But it's only the surface. The unmutable keywords are a small percent of the language power. Most of it lies in objects and methods exported by the system, and these are fully mutable. You can replace/extend methods on the fly, you can replace pretty deeply rooted system methods, nest `eval()`, load generated `<SCRIPT>` on the fly, and so on. This is usable in writing all kinds of language extensions, frameworks, toolboxes and such. Instead of 200 lines of code of your program in straightforward Javascript, you write 50 lines that modify how Javascript work, and another 50 that use the new syntax to get the work done. You can generate whole pages on the fly, including JS embedded in them. You turn webpage structure into data storage. You replace frequently used methods of popular objects, and your own, to change their behavior on the fly, changing not only looks but also function of a webpage in one click.

It really feels like Javascript becomes a metalanguage to modify the Javascript engine, and make Javascript function like a different language, then you further modify it using the already modified, and your actual, final app takes a dozen of extremely intuitive lines getting the language do exactly what it needs. Oh, and patches the countless bugs and shortcomings of Javascript implementation on MSIE in the process.

Answer (score 1):

I won't claim Lisp is the "most dynamic" (I'm not even sure what that means), but Lisp programmers frequently do things that are difficult-to-impossible in other languages:

- create new control structures
- create new syntax for existing constructs (I think every metaclass I've ever seen has its own defwhatever form)
- extend the runtime (every .emacs is a runtime extension, e.g., what would it take to write calendar-mode for another editor?)

Yegge [talks about it some here](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/the-emacs-problem) w.r.t. Emacs, e.g., parse XML by converting it to s-expressions, writing functions for the tags you want to process, and actually running it.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it's not languages that write dynamic code, it's programmers; and there's going to be a learning curve to adjust your patterns to styles you're not used to. So what types of work can make best use of dynamic capabilities? The first that comes to my mind is middleware; interfaces among heterogeneous systems; especially those with imperfectly documented APIs or APIs that change a lot, and data serialization is dynamic.

I'd say anywhere you see REST and jason being applied, you're more likely to find dynamic code, for instance, where javascript, php, perl, ruby, ... are popular at least partially because they are capable of dynamic adaptation.

Also, there's a lot of javascript browser code that deals with browser version and brand incmpatiblities using dynamic techniques.

Comment: JSON can be parsed quite statically and does not really require dynamic evaluation though it's usable quite concisely in this context.

Comment: You're right, of course. Any of this can be done statically, somehow. The question was about code style and point-of-view. To me, jason is duck-typed data, and matches up well with duck-typing languages. Remember, what json is, is serialized javascript object declarations - dynamically self-defining, untyped data (including objects).

Answer (score 0):

Yes i feel JavaScript as good one. 
JavaScript is so flexible that people working on different languages have different variants of it for them. Like Microsoft has Ajax library which has typical .NET/C# type syntax. Also there are some JavaScript libraries which uses $ which looks similar like PHP syntaxes. Its all there because JavaScript is bueaty How many other languages one can tell which can facilitates something like this? 
And one should know about the JavaScript closure feature which is state of art and help create amazing algorithms with great results.